# Add a decimal (.) to a String before converting into an int

Tags: java

I have a barcode I am reading from a text file in java. I am separating the bar code into parts and each part means something different. The las 4 digits of the barcode are the price but when I read it is a string then I have to transform it to an int.

```
// this is the bar code that is in the text file
// 10009999991020162590
File myFile = new File ("data.txt");
Scanner  inFile = new Scanner (myFile);

barCode = inFile.nextLine();
departmentStore = (Integer.parseInt(barCode.substring(0,4)));
partNumber = (Integer.parseInt(barCode.substring(4,10)));
date = (Integer.parseInt(barCode.substring(10,16)));
price = (Integer.parseInt(barCode.substring(16,20))); 

/*this is the price of the las 4 digits of the bar code as you can 
see is a string first but then i have to convert it into a int so i can do math but i want 
to put a dot(.) between the 25.90 then transform to int.

*/
```

Comment: 26.90 is not an int.

Comment: If you're looking for an answer, you ought to ask a question.

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes he said the truth it is a floating or double type number

Comment: @javafan He said he wants to transform it to an int. That's impossible.

Comment: @shmosel correct reply he seems not to have asked a question.

Comment: An integer is a whole number, like 100, 25, 56. A number with a decimal point is not an integer, but rather a fraction; commonly called a _float_.

Comment: Curious...what if the price in the bar code was actually 625.90?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would suggest first you parse it to an int value and then  generate the decimal value. It is possible to put a decimal character in the string but then when you convert it to int it will either generate NumberFormatException or Simply discard the after decimal values.

So it's better you convert it to int and then devide the value by 100 or 100.0 to get the desired output.

Comment: Can you please show an example of this technique providing a precise monetary value as an integer. Thank you.

Comment: #if you are ok with the type double go with            double price=Double.parseDouble(barCode.substring(16,20)) / 100;.                                                                                       #If you want value in int only you have to go with        int wholeValue = Integer.parseInt(barCode.substring(16,20)) / 100;         int precisionValue = Integer.parseInt(barCode.substring(16,20)) % 100;

Answer (score 1):

Note as we all discussed in comments it is not possible to store a floating number in an integer variable.It seems that you want to store the number in a double for calculation by putting a .(dot) between two digits.Its not a tough task just note the code.

```
.
.
.
.
String price=barCode.substring(16,20);
//get first two part of string add a . and then the last two char
price=price.substring(0,2)+"."+price.substring(2,4);
//then convert it to double
double p=Double.parseDouble(price);
```

Also there is a simple way to do that.
.
.

```
int price = (Integer.parseInt(barCode.substring(16,20))); 
double p=price/100.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're placing a decimal, then it wont be an `int` you'd have to store it in a `float` or `double`

You can use simple String concatenation for this trivial task.

```
double price = Double.parseDouble(barCode.substring(16,18) + "." + barCode.substring(18,20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 (bad):

```
float price = (Float.parseFloat(
               barCode.substring(16,18) + "." + barCode.substring(18,20)));
```

I am not entirely sure about locales. Will java parse independant of locale settings? In Germany for instance, a correct decimal value is written as `25,90` and not `25.90`. So I'd suggest you use a more universal approach instead of the hardcoded `.`.

Option 2 (better, imho):

```
float price = Float.parseFloat(String.format("%02.2f", 
             (float)(Integer.parseInt(barCode.substring(16,20))) / 100.0f));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what you want to do with the price variable after parsing.

Here's a few options:

1. You can think of the last 4 digits of the barcode as **price in pennies**:

   ```
   int priceInPennies = Integer.parseInt(barCode.substring(16,20));
   ```
2. Keep the price in pennies or convert it to **price in dollars**:

   ```
   double priceInDollars = Double.parseDouble(barCode.substring(16,20)) / 100;
   ```

   or

   ```
   double priceInDollars = priceInPennies / 100.0;
   ```
3. If you need the price for display purposes only, why not just keep the **price as a String**:

   ```
   String priceAsString = barCode.substring(16,18) + "." + barCode.substring(18,20);
   ```